# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not reader

Tags: python

I'm trying to read numerous csv files and search for the word 'error'.

Using csv.reader is causing an issue as I believe it is looking for a string.

I'm not sure if changing to text would help?

```
import glob
import os # Imported os
import csv
import pathlib

def find_cell(csv_file, check):
    with open(csv_file,'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            for col_idx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell == check:
                    return row_idx, col_idx
    return None

def errorCheck(Filename):

    is_match = False

    with open(Filename) as f:
        csv_file = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
        check = 'Error'
        cell_location = find_cell(csv_file, check)
        if cell_location:
            row_idx, col_idx = cell_location
            print("ERROR")
            print_and_log('ERROR IN FILE - '+ Filename + 'row '+ {row_idx} +'column ' + {col_idx})
            is_match = True
    if is_match:
        return
```

Comment: Please clarify by providing samples of the file content passed to *errorCheck()* and subsequently the CSV files that you're trying to process in *find_cell()*

Answer (score 1):

`open()` takes any of `str`, `bytes` or `os.PathLike`. Calling `open()` with a `csv.reader()` like you did will throw the error.

Instead consider passing `Filename` directly to `find_cell()` instead of `reading` first since `find_cell()` will still perform a `read`.

```
def errorCheck(Filename):
    is_match = False
    check = 'Error'
    cell_location = find_cell(Filename, check)
    if cell_location:
        row_idx, col_idx = cell_location
        print("ERROR")
        print_and_log('ERROR IN FILE - '+ Filename + 'row '+ {row_idx} +'column ' + {col_idx})
        is_match = True
    if is_match:
        return
```

What did I do? I removed the file context because it is not needed since `find_cell()` will eventually `open()` the file.

Comment: Thank you for this, if I remove the open() from the second part of my statement the next part of the script doesn't open the files. Do I need to add it back in?

Comment: The idea is that `find_cell()` will do all the opening needed. Just use the modifications I made.